# What does the symbol ; }) mean?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, tour

What does the symbol `; })` mean? In all the Stack Exchange site's [Tour](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tour) pages, I can see the symbol.

Is it a smiley? Or is it due to a code block not being closed properly?

> [image: ; })]

Comment: I would re-tag this as a bug, because it most-likely is. Looks like some issue in the template. Another indicator is that the `; })` is placed outside the `div` used to style the text above.

Comment: It's obvious. It is a guy with a curly mustache making a wink and smiling.

Comment: I would re-tag this as *Yaakov-the-Wizard did it on purpose to earn the fix-it-faster-than-the-speed-of-light-because-it's-the-only-one-missing-in-my-drawer hat* :D

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`; })` is removed.

As to what it means: Obviously it is a winking smiley face with a mustache