# Strange semicolons on the email settings page

Tags: bug, status-completed, preferences

https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/email/settings/current

> [image: Semicolon on the email settings page]

And:

> [image: Semicolon on the email settings page 2]

Comment: The arrows should have been red freehand circles. Please fix ASAP.

Comment: This time [}) is missing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340637/312043)

Comment: Fix is arriving in 6;8 weeks;;

Comment: @ShadowWizardisEarForYou it's ok. [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316766/260198) issue hasn't been fixed for year (: